# How to set working directory in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to transform an XML using XSLT(transform.xsl). In transform.xsl, i need to import some supporting xml and xsl files. So i will have to set working directory to access the supporting files. Please suggest how to set working directory before xsl:import

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative URI then it is resolved against the base URI which you can set and change anywhere in XML using the `xml:base` attribute e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xml:base="http://example.com/xslt" ...>` or `<xsl:stylesheet xml:base="file:///C:/dir/subdir" ...>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the response. I should be able to set the working directory dynamically from where it should pick supporting xml and xsl documents. Could you please suggest?

Comment: How are you using XSLT, in some kind of program written in a certain programming language? Then you need to ask how to set a working directory in a program in that programming language. XSLT or XML don't know a working directory. And if you have a specific problem or error the please explain that in your question, providing some details, as usually if you have your stylesheet modules in a directory and load the main stylesheet which then uses `xsl:include href="someModule.xsl"` to include additional modules there is no problem.

Comment: I am invoking XSLT through an ETL tool. By default it is referring to tool directory as working directory.